# How do I list old TFS users that no longer belong to any security groups?

Tags: security, version-control, tfs, tfs-sdk

There are lots of examples around that show how to get a list of current TFS users, but how do I get a list of old users that have commit changes in the past but no longer belong to any security groups?

For the record, this is the code I'm using to find all current users:

```
var gss = tfs.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
var members = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.EveryoneApplicationGroup,
                               null,
                               QueryMembership.Expanded).Members;
return gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, members, QueryMembership.None)
    .Where(identity => identity != null &&
                       identity.Type == IdentityType.WindowsUser)
    .Select(identity => string.Format(@"{0}\{1}",
                                      identity.Domain,
                                      identity.AccountName));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't offer an exact answer, but hopefully this will help...

You can list all pending changes through the workspaces (i.e. tf.exe workspaces command and equivalent apis). Using the owner of each workspace with uncommitted changes you should then be able to cross-reference against the list of active users you've already got.

Comment: Good idea, that gets me a little closer! Unfortunately it looks like some old users have had their workspaces deleted too.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should reveal each and every person that has ever committed changes in your TeamCollection repository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace PeopleWhoHaveCommitedChangesets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFSServer:8080"));
            VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer) tpc.GetService(typeof (VersionControlServer));
            IEnumerable results = vcs.QueryHistory(@"$/",
                                                    VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, null, null, int.MaxValue, true, true);
            List<Changeset> changesets = results.Cast<Changeset>().ToList();

            List<string> Users = new List<string>();
            foreach (var changeset in changesets)
            {
                if(!Users.Contains(changeset.Owner))
                {
                    Users.Add(changeset.Owner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beware that this is a brute force, and, with a lot of changesets, it would take considerable time to execute.

Comment: I have over 100k changesets so I was trying to avoid this approach, however it doesn't look there's any other way.

Comment: I see... Well, there is this table in TFS SQL `tbl_ChangeSet`: you are after the distinct people behind entries in Column `OwnerId`. Couldn't find a way to map an `OwnerID` to a Username though...